# How to create alias with g++?

Tags: g++, alias

I'm trying to create an alias on ubuntu for the bellow commands:

```
g++ -lSDL -lSDLmain -lSDL_image -lGL -lGLU src.cpp -o a.out
g++ -lGL -lglut `sdl-config --cflags --libs` src.cpp -o a.out
```

When I execute them in the terminal all goes very well, but if I create aliases for them I find the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.text+0x18): error: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
bash: -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
```

The aliases are:

```
alias g++="g++ -lGL -lglut `sdl-config --cflags --libs`"
alias gcpp="g++ -lSDL -lSDLmain -lSDL_image -lGL -lGLU"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following alias and it worked well.

```
alias g+++="g++ -lSDL -lSDLmain -lSDL_image -lGL -lGLU"
```

The first does not work.